# PHP MySQL extract field then split at double spaces

Tags: php, sql

I have a table which contains rows, within each row there is a field which contains peoples names seperated by a double space.

I need to extract this field from each row, then split the field into separate names and dump into another table.

What's the best way to do this? Do I split it within the sql query or extract the fields then split using PHP?

New info:

OK, the field contains full names e.g. john doe, tom smith etc etc the double spaces separate the full names e.g.

```
JOHN DOE  TOM SMITH  JOHN WOO
```

There might be one name in the field but there could also be potentialy up to 10

Thanks

Darren

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can do it in sql. should be something like this:

```
INSERT INTO tbl_dest (first_name, last_name) VALUES

(SELECT
    LEFT(ts.name, LOCATE('  ',ts.name)) AS first_name,
    SUBSTRING(ts.name, LOCATE('  ',ts.name)+2) AS last_name
FROM tbl_source AS ts)
```

as @Marc B stated, it will only work if the data is consistent (ie each row's name field contains a double space and the first double space separates the name and password.
you can ignore other rows (without the double space) by simply adding

```
INSERT ...
(SELECT   ... 
FROM tbl_source AS ts WHERE LOCATE('  ', ts.name) > 0)
```

if the field starts with a double space (ie first name is empty) it will also be ignored

**EDIT:**

since you said that each row can contain multiple pairs of first/last name. here's a code example:

```
$query = "SELECT `name` FROM `tbl_source`";
$res = mysql_query($query, $link);
$names = array();
while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($res)) {
    $nmlist = explode('  ',$row['name']);
    for($i=0, $n=count($nmlist); $i<$n-1; $i+=2){
        $names[] = "('" . mysql_real_escape_string(stripslashes($nmlist[$i])) ."',"
                   ."'" . mysql_real_escape_string(stripslashes($nmlist[$i+1])) ."')";
    }
}
$insert_query = "INSERT INTO `tbl_dest` (`first_name`,`last_name`) VALUES "
          .implode(',', $names);
mysql_query($insert_query, $link);
```

in this example, double spaces are between first name and last name, and between each pair

Comment: Thanks guys, Yeah, i neglected to mention there could be 2 full names in the field or there could be up to 10 full names

Comment: will there always be full names? i mean, the value of the field will be "f1  l1  f2  l2 ..." ?always in this format? what separates each first_name-last_name pair?

Comment: double spaces separate each first_name-last_name pair

Answer (score 1):

I'm not familiar with a MySQL solution for this.

I suggest grabbing the information you need, using `explode('  ', $info);` and then inserting back into the database.

Comment: if you do this, make sure you are selecting all data and join the strings into 1 insert query and not doing a separate insert for every tuple

Comment: Good point. By the way, in the first argument of explode() I had typed two spaces but it looks like it only put one in my answer. Remember to use two as you specified in the question.

Comment: @galchen can you elaborate on that, how do you mean 1 insert query? they need to go on a different line each

Comment: select all fields, and then create the query string: INSERT INTO tbl_dest (first_name, last_name) VALUES (f1,l1),(f2,l2).....(fn,ln) - ie join all the inserted data into one query string